# How to run Remote Desktop Connection Manager in command line

Tags: batch-file, rdp, mstsc

I'm using RDCM 2.2 (Remote Desktop Connection Manager) want to write a batch script to run RDMC and connect server group in specific time by scheduling this .bat file and close program with Task Scheduler.

I scan through help doc of RDCM, I found nothing except following ;

> By default, RDCMan will open the files that were loaded at the time of the last program shutdown. You can override this by specifying a file (or files) explicitly on the RDCMan command line. Additionally, the following switches are accepted:
>
> •/reset - reset the persisted application preferences such as window location and size.
>
> •/noopen - do not open the previously loaded files, start with a blank environment.

I got stuck w/ missing information whether RDCM supports command line parameters or not. Is there any good practice to realize this?

Thanks.

Semanur

Comment: Why don't you use Plink from Putty tools? It is a command line client that works through SSH.

Comment: Access is not permitted through SSH protocol.

Answer (score 3):

For RDCMan 2.7 I see the following options for the commandline in the helpfile:

> **Command Line**
>
> By default, RDCMan will open the files that were loaded at the time of the last program shutdown. 
>   You can override this by specifying a file (or files) explicitly on the RDCMan command line.
>   Additionally, the following switches are accepted:
>
> **/reset** - reset the persisted application preferences such as window location and size.
>
> **/noopen** - do not open the previously loaded files, starting with an empty environment.
>
> **/c server1[,server2...]** - connect specified servers /reconnect - connect all servers that were connected at shutdown without prompting
>
> **/noconnect** - do not prompt to connect servers that were connected at shutdown